# App Store rejection reasons - is it online or only in email?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am a developer publishing an app through my clients' iTunesConnect portal. My first submission was rejected, and my client had to forward the rejection email to me. Is there somewhere online I can view why my app was rejected? I have searched around iTunesConnect and googled it and can't seem to find out.

My goal is to not require my client to have to forward each email to me. I will be developing a bunch of apps for them through this method.

Comment: They just have to assign a proper role in their team to your AppleID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in iTunes Connect to your App, then click on the "Activity" tab near the top center, then "App Store Versions" on the left hand side it will give you a breakdown of the approval process.  The latest progress update will be "Rejected."  From there you can go to the "Resolution Center" to view correspondences between the review board and yourself (or your client).

[Apple link for reference on the Resolution Center.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW28)